# Como actualizar etiqueta <p> con el valor de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Necesito actualizar el valor del precio segun el value de uno o varios checkbox

```html
@foreach($componentes as $comp)
<input type='checkbox' id="check" onclick="actualiza()" name='componentes[{{$comp->nombre_componente}}]' class="custom-control-input" value='{{$comp->precio}}'> <span>{{$comp->nombre_componente}} + {{$comp->precio}}€   </span>
@endforeach
               
<br>
<p class="costetotal" id="costetotal"></p>
```

Comment: Querés actualizarlo mediante PHP o javascript? Veo que tenés una función `actualiza()`, qué intentaste hacer? Estás usando alguna librería de javascript?

Comment: La idea es que haya x checkbox generados dinamicamente y que al seleccionar / deseleccionar se actualice el valor de p con el valor correspondientes de cada uno, sumándose al estar marcado y restándose al ser desmarcado, preferiblemente en Js o Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le agregué la clase `precio` a cada uno de los checkbox. Ojo porque los `ID` de tus checkbox son todos iguales, deberías agregarle algo para diferenciarlos.

Cada vez que clickeas alguno, recorre todos los checkbox y suma los que están tildados.

```js
function actualiza() {
    var total = 0;
    var precios = document.querySelectorAll('.precio');
  
    precios.forEach(function (precio) {
        total += precio.checked ? parseInt(precio.value) : 0;
    });
  
    document.getElementById('costetotal').innerHTML = total + '€';
}
```

```html
<label for="check1">10€</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="check1" onclick="actualiza()" name='componentes[nombre]' class="custom-control-input precio" value='10'>

<label for="check2">15€</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="check2" onclick="actualiza()" name='componentes[nombre]' class="custom-control-input precio" value='15'>

<label for="check3">20€</label>
<input type='checkbox' id="check3" onclick="actualiza()" name='componentes[nombre]' class="custom-control-input precio" value='20'>

<p class="costetotal" id="costetotal">0€</p>
```

Con jQuery podrías hacer algo así (sacando el onclick):

```
var costetotal = 0;

$('.precio').on('change', function () {
    var precio = parseInt(this.value);
    costetotal += this.checked ? precio : -precio;
    $('#costetotal').text(costetotal + '€');
});
```

Mismo enfoque con JS (hay que cambiar el onclick a `actualiza(this)` y la clase `precio` ya no hace falta):

```
var costetotal = 0;

function actualiza(checkbox) {
    var precio = parseInt(checkbox.value);
    costetotal += checkbox.checked ? precio : -precio;
    document.getElementById('costetotal').innerHTML = costetotal + '€';
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, así si. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, en el foreach crear varios elementos **input** con el mismo **id**, deberías evitar eso.

Crea el **checkbox** extableciendo un ID unico como podria ser el siguiente

```
// Su id se veria algo asi: id="valor_420"
<input type='checkbox' id="valor_{{$comp->precio}}" onclick="actualiza(this.value)" name='componentes[{{$comp->nombre_componente}}]' class="custom-control-input" value='{{$comp->precio}}'>
```

Como ves, al hacer click le pasas su propio valor. Luego, en la funcion

```
// Le pasamos el valor
function actualiza(valor){
    // Seleccionamos la etiqueta <p> y le establecemos el valor
    document.getElementById('costetotal').innerHTML = valor
}
```

O bien, puedes establecer el valor directamente en la funcion en vez de establecerlo en el propio input y evitas crear el **id**

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick="actualiza({{$comp->precio}})" name='componentes[{{$comp->nombre_componente}}]' class="custom-control-input" value='{{$comp->precio}}'>
```

Otro detalle, a la hora de establecer el **name**, recuerda que deberían tener todos el mismo

Comment: La idea es que haya x checkbox generados dinamicamente y que al seleccionar / deseleccionar se actualice el valor de p con el valor correspondientes de cada uno, sumándose al estar marcado y restándose al ser desmarcado, preferiblemente en Js o Jquery